# Website Home loads fine on retina display screens for just one second....then it scales up (or zoom in)

Tags: web, scale, web-testing

So im finishing a website and for some reason, the homepage zooms in on retina displays. When you load it, it looks great for 1 seconds and then auto scales and some content is no longer visible. Keep in mind this only happens on the homepage (which is an horizontal scrolling page)
https://www.vacka.es

Maybe someone has an idea on what might be causeing this??

NOTE: If you are not using a retina display or a high res display (2k or more) you wont be able to see the problem.

I tried some CSS code like `transform: scale(70%);` but it does not work